# Multiple samplers for one texture array

Tags: opengl, textures, fragment-shader

- How can I create multiple samplers for one texture array?

So far I have relied upon OpenGL figuring out that the declared `uniform sampler2Darray txa` sampler refers to the texture array I bound with `glBindTexture`.

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0,  GL_RGBA8, width, height,
             layerCount,  0 GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_array);
...
glGenTextures(1,&texture_ID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture_ID); 
... 
                               //fragment shader
uniform sampler2Darray txa
...
vec2 tc;
tc.x = (1.0f - tex_coord.x) * tex_quad[0] + tex_coord.x * tex_quad[1];
tc.y = (1.0f - tex_coord.y) * tex_quad[2] + tex_coord.y * tex_quad[3];
vec4 sampled_color = texture(txa, vec3(tc, tex_id));
```

I tried specifying two samplers in the fragment shader but I get a compilation error for the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2DArray txa;
uniform sampler2DArray txa2;
...
vec4 texture = texture(txa, vec3(tc, tex_id));
vec4 texture2 = texture(txa2, vec3(tc2, tex_id));
```

I didn't expect this to work, however, I am not sure that the fragment shader compilator checks whether samplers are assigned textures, so maybe something else is wrong.

I tried generating and binding the sampler objects but I still get a fragment shader error:

```
GLuint sampler_IDs[2];
glGenSamplers(2,sampler_IDs);
glBindSampler(texture_ID, sampler_IDs[0]);
glBindSampler(texture_ID, sampler_IDs[1]);
```

I would like to stick to lower versions of OpenGL, is it possible? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: *"I get a compilation error for the fragment shader:"* - What is the error message?

Comment: error C1105: cannot call a non-function

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you for fixing my bug again! :D So I don't need to create samplers outside of the shader program unless they have different sampling settings? I.e. they all inherit from `glTexParameteri`?

Comment: [`glTexParameteri`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml) does not set global states. It sets the parameters for the single texture object which is currently bound to the specified target (the target is `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` in your case). You've to set the parameters for each texture object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is cause by the line

> ```c
> vec4 texture = texture(txa, vec3(tc, tex_id));
> ```

Then name of the variable `texture` is equal the name of the built-in function [`texture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml). The variable is declared in local scope, so in this scope `texture` is a variable and calling the function `texture` causes an error.

Rename the variable to solve the issue. e.g.:

```c
vec4 texture1 = texture(txa, vec3(tc, tex_id));
```